# why do I get different date value after I pass the datetime from javascript to php?

Tags: php, javascript, date, datetime, time

I have a php for handling the time stuff:

```
[PHP]echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['time']);
```

Then I hava a javascript to post the a time value to the php:

```
[javascript]var $new_time = Math.round((new Date("2009-09-09T23:15:00")).getTime()/1000);
            $.ajax({
              url:"...",
              data:{time:$new_time},
              type: "post",
              async: false,
              dataType: "html",
              success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                     alert(data);   
              }
            });
```

And in the alert, it shows: `2009-09-10 01:15:00`. Hm, can anyone tell me why is that?

Comment: JavaScript is client side.  It is based off of your computer's system clock.  PHP is server-side.  It is based off of the server's system time and timezone information.

Comment: how does round'ing a date work?

Comment: @Dagon The OP was probably trying to round the `Date.getTime()`, but did it incorrectly.

Comment: @Gagon, I am not very sure why is that? but if I don't round it, the function does not even work. I think this has something to do with the conversion between javascript datetime and unix datetime format.

Comment: @BLaZuRe, thanks for the advice. And in fact, I have set the php sever to the right timezone by adding ini_set('date.timezone', <my location>) in my php file. So, why would this still be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike with most other formats, when given a date string in [ISO format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), JavaScript assumes it's in UTC.

```
var date = new Date("2009-09-09T23:15:00");

console.log(date.toUTCString()); // Wed, 09 Sep 2009 23:15:00 GMT
```

While PHP is outputting the date for the system's *local* timezone.

If you prefer the date be in UTC/GMT all-around, you can use [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/gmdate):

```php
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['time']);
```

Comment: I see, so is there any method or function to make the php thinks that it is a time of local timezone? or is there any method to deduce 2009-09-09T23:15:00 back to its corresponding UTC time format?

Comment: I know I can write a function to deduce the time to the right format. just wondering if there is any easy function from javascript library or jquery to be called to do this.

Comment: @Newbie You can try using `gmdate()`. Added a link to the docs and update snippet.

Comment: Instead of `gmdate()` start using `DateTime` class. It has great timezone support.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will use the end user's local computer clock where PHP will use the time and timezone settings of the remote server. Try creating a sample page that outputs the current time and timezone offset in PHP and compare that with the computer you are on.